# Swiping through content on Blackberry Playbook

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air, blackberry-playbook

I am creating a Playbook app in Adobe Flex/AIR.

I have a situation where there is too much content to show all on one page so I would like it where the content overflows vertically, the user can swipe to scroll down, like they were viewing a website on an Ipad.

I am extending the [View](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/View.html) class to make my screens, I could place every screen in a one element [List](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/List.html) or surround it all in a [Scroller](http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/spark/components/Scroller.html) but surely there must be an inbuilt way to do this on the Playbook?

With the limited Blackberry documentation, I'm struggling to find the solution, any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm  developing my own Blackberry Playbook app myself. Here's some advice:

1. Take a look at the [List View](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/23959/Displaying_data_in_lists_1447751_11.jsp) options available. You might be interested in using a TileList
2. Review listening for [Swipe Events](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/23959/Responding_to_events_1425036_11.jsp) to update the position of your List (be it TileList or SectionList).
3. Check out the [Blackberry Tablet documentation](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/?userType=21). It's not that limited!